# Connect AWS Cloud HSM directly from local Machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hsm

Is it Possible to directly connect to AWS CLoud HSM directly through Local Machine for Development Purpose, Or do we need to compulsorily instantiate an EC2 to connect and work with CLoud HSM.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a micro/small instance on public subnet of VPC, assign public ip (or elastic ip if you want), install a vpn (easy openvpn install: https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install), after you connect to vpn you can act like you are on same VPC with CloudHSM.

Note: make sure that your vpn client on your local machine is routing traffic to vpn, you can either configure that from client or push route from vpn server.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your client must be in the VPC of the CloudHSM. So if you want to use your "local machine" I guess your laptop to the CloudHSM, you have to use AWS VPN or if you have on-premises server, use AWS Direct Connect.